# usar withcolumn o un simple select con alias(Scala)

Tags: rendimiento, scala, apache-spark

Estoy empezando a trabajar con Dataset,y en algunos compañeros comentan que para el performance de una operación es mejor utilizar un select con una subconsulta y agregar un alias, que utilizar un withcolumn.

Entiendo que al agregar un **withcolumn** estoy generando un dataframe por cada vez que lo use, lo cual puede generar perdidas de performance.

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien la pregunta,

- Si te refieres a la select usando `.sql` por debajo entraría catalyst y tendría que traducir la sql.
- Si te refieres a la performance de los Dataset vs los DataFrame spark tiene que serializar y convertir todos los datos a tipos de la JVM.
- Si te refieres a usar una UDF, intenta evitarlas siempre que puedas.
- Agregar columnas no tiene porque crear diferentes DataFrames cada vez, recuerda que Spark es lazy y tiene el optimizador

Para mi gusto es mejor usar DataFrame con withcolumn, con todas las ventajas y desventajas que puede conllevar, luego entra lo que te da trabajar con Dataset que hasta en tiempo de compilación puedes ver errores, y luego tratar con sql, todo tiene sus ventajas y su performance (depende también de los propios recursos del cluster, la agilidad para tirar querys ...)